# Arraylist search for 2 elements in a specified order

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to make a code, that can search for 2 elements in an arraylist. Order of elements is important. Searched elements: `adjLists.get(l).get(h), adjLists.get(l).get(h+1)`

```
List list=new ArrayList();
list.add(adjLists.get(l).get(h));
list.add(adjLists.get(l).get(h+1));

for(List<Integer> arrayList:adjLists) {
   while (arrayList.containsAll(list)) {
    arrayList.set(arrayList.indexOf(adjLists.get(l).get(h + 1) + 1), 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Collections.indexOfSublist

```
    int i = Collections.indexOfSubList(list, Arrays.asList(o1, o2));
```

Comment: Like this: `int j = Collections.indexOfSubList(adjLists, Arrays.asList(adjLists.get(l).get(h), adjLists.get(l).get(h+1)));` ? After that how can I search?

Comment: if i == -1 then search failed; otherwise it is index of the first element, i+1 is the index of the second element

Comment: Which loop and how should be used? Please give me more details, collections are new for me.

Comment: Index? In which list? I think 2 numbers are needed to identify an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
    if (list.get(i) == firstVal && list.get(i+1) == secondVal) {
        // Victory!
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is a list of lists, there are 2 gets. I have already tried this, do not working.

Comment: `for (int lj = 0; lj < arraynum; lj++) {
    for (int lk = 0; lk < adjLists.get(lj).size(); lk+=3) {
        if (adjLists.get(lj).get(lk) == adjLists.get(l).get(h)
            && adjLists.get(lj).get(lk + 1) == adjLists.get(l).get(h + 1)) {
            adjLists.get(lj).set(lk + 2, 1);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This cide do the same as yours, but is not working, do seemly nothing.

Comment: Yes, that causes the problem.